# Dynamic stack in C [pop crash]

Tags: c, dynamic, stack

Im making a program to convert a decimal int to binary using a dynamic stack.
It crashes on the last pop.
ex. num: 4  output: 10crash

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct stack {
    struct stack *prev;
    int val;
    struct stack *next;
};
struct stack *first,*cur,*tmp;
struct stack *GETNODE(){
    struct stack *pt = (struct stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
};
int counter=1;
void push(int val){
    tmp=GETNODE();
    tmp->prev=NULL;
    tmp->val=val;
    tmp->next=NULL;
    if(first==NULL){
        first=tmp;
        cur=first;
    }else{
        tmp->prev=cur;
        cur->next=tmp;
        cur=tmp;
    }
    counter++;
};

int pop(){
    int val=tmp->val;
    cur=tmp->prev;
    free(tmp);
    tmp=cur;
    tmp->next=NULL;
    counter--;
    return(val);
};


main(){
    int num = 4;
    while(num!=0){
        push(num%2);
        num/=2;
    }
    while(counter!=1){
        printf("%d ",pop());
    }
}
```

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc()`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845)

Comment: MSVC Compiler warning C4716: `'GETNODE' : must return a value.`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart this is how the teacher told us to do it, plus it does not seem to be the problem

Comment: Please tell your teacher to `#include <stdlib.h>` ,too.

Comment: If your teacher really thinks casts are a substitute for correct declarations, you need a new teacher. Tell them that.

Comment: Also `main()` hasn't been a valid declaration for a while. `int main(void)` is correct. Also, checking the return value of `malloc` is not optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your pop function.  If you think about how it operates, in the final pass you will free(tmp), which is currently pointing to the very first item.  After you free it, you then assign:

```
tmp->next=NULL;
```

You are trying to dereference an invalid pointer at this point.

Comment: whops, thank you! i would never notice that

Comment: You *would* notice it if you stepped through your code with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I made a lot of changes to your code. Mainly, it was far too complicated - only a singly linked list was needed, and you don't need a counter - just track the list pointer. Your `GETNODE()` function did not return a value, causing undefined behaviour in the calling function. I simplified that too, there is no need for a separate function to allocate memory because `malloc()` already does that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack {
    struct stack *prev;
    int val;
};

struct stack *first = NULL;

void push(int val){
    struct stack *pt = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    if (pt == NULL){
        printf ("Bad call to malloc()\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    pt->prev=first;
    pt->val=val;
    first = pt;
}

int pop(){
    int val;
    struct stack *pt = first;
    if (first == NULL)
        return -1;
    val=first->val;
    first = first->prev;
    free(pt);
    return(val);
}

void dec2bin(int num){
    printf("%-5d", num);
    while(num!=0){
        push(num%2);
        num/=2;
    }
    while(first){
        printf("%d",pop());
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void){
    dec2bin (4);
    dec2bin (129);
    dec2bin (160);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
4    100
129  10000001
160  10100000
```

Answer (score 0):

I change some part of your code and your code working now.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

struct stack {
     struct stack *prev;
     int val;
     struct stack *next;
};

struct stack *first, *cur, *tmp;
int counter = 0;

struct stack *GETNODE()
{
     return malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
}


void push(int val)
{
    tmp = GETNODE();
    tmp->prev = NULL;
    tmp->val = val;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    if (first == NULL) {
         first = tmp;
         cur = first;
    } else {
         tmp->prev = cur;
         cur->next = tmp;
         cur = tmp;
    }
    counter++;
}

int pop(void)
{
     int val = cur->val;

     tmp = cur;
     cur = cur->prev;
     free(tmp);
     counter--;

     return val;
 }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num;

    scanf("%d", &num);

    while (num != 0) {
        push(num % 2);
        num /= 2;
    }
    while (counter != 0)
    printf("%d ", pop());
    printf("\n");
}
```